# How to see diffs of ODT files in Bazaar?

Tags: versioning, archive, bazaar, odt

By default, bzr diff does not show differences in binary files. However, a large part of ODT (open office, libre office) files contain XML data under the surface. (ODT stores xml data as an archive (zip ?))

Is there a plugin which allows bazaar to look into archives? Or are there any special plugins for ODT documents?

Answer (score 2):

The "official" branch of the `oodiff` plugin is out of date, and doesn't work with the latest version of Bazaar.

I created a new branch with bugfixes, it should work better. You can install with:

```
bzr branch lp:~janos-gyerik/bzr-oodiff/fixes-for-bzr2.5 ~/.bazaar/plugins/oodiff
```

I tested it with a few ODT files and it works for differences in the working tree and differences in past revisions.

Answer (score 1):

From the description, the following plugin should do the job:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/oodiff.html

Comment: Ok, gave it a short try, but it fails (on get_default_plugin_path). Probably a version differnce between my bazaar and oodiffs'